# Button spanning 2 fragments (xml layout)

Tags: android, xml

Can't figure out how to set this up in XML...

Trying to get a button to lay over 2 fragments that sit behind it.

What I want:

[image]

What I have:

[image]

My code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context=".VulgarActivity" 
    >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/luckBtn"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/feel_lucky"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        />
    <fragment
        android:name="com.wizardknight.visionaryvulgarity.FirstWord"
        android:id="@+id/firstWord"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
    <fragment
        android:name="com.wizardknight.visionaryvulgarity.LastWord"
        android:id="@+id/lastWord"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />  
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a `RelativeLayout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/firstWord"
            android:name="com.wizardknight.visionaryvulgarity.FirstWord"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/lastWord"
            android:name="com.wizardknight.visionaryvulgarity.LastWord"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/luckBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:text="@string/feel_lucky"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

### Explanation:

The difference between `RelativeLayout` and `LinearLayout` is simple. `LinearLayouts` order their child views, like the name already says, linearly. That means, that the child will order themselves, depending on the orientation of the `LinearLayout`, vertically or horizontally to each other. The child view of a `RelativeLayout` on the other hand order themselves *relative* to the parent view or to other views. In this layout I just changed the parent layout to `RelativeLayout` and wrapped your fragments in a `LinearLayout`, so it they can use the `layout_weight` attribute. Then I set this to the button:

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

This aligns the button to the bottom and centers them horizontally. Now, since it does this relative to the top level layout, it overlaps the fragment.

Comment: Thanks a ton... now let me ask a question.  I tried nested linear layouts and ended up getting them next to each other rather than on top of each other.  This is my first time using fragments so I'm making something stupid and fun for practice... what is it about the relative layout that allows these to stack that linear doesn't have?